# How to count the uppercase and lowercase letters in string writing lesser code?

Tags: python

I have been trying to count the uppercase and lowercase letters, then by comparing them, I'm trying to print the string either in uppercase or lowercase based on some conditions. In the first method my code worked and output showed but it looks messy, so I tried the 2nd way to make it look shorter and less clumsy. But my code is not working.

```
str1="HEY tHeRE Whats UP"
upper1,lower1=0,0
for i in range(len(str1)):
  if str1[i].isupper():
    upper1+=1
  if str1[i].islower():
    lower1+=1
if upper1>lower1:
  print(str1.upper())
else:
  print(str1.lower())
```

2nd way:

```
def count_up_and_low(word):
  u = [x for x in word if x.isupper()]
  l = [x for x in word if x.islower()]
  return len(u),len(l) 
word="HEY THERE WHATS up"
count_up_and_low(word)
if u>l:
  print(word.upper())
else:
  print(word.lower())
```

here only showes in lowercase letter eve if the number of uppercase letters are more

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error or are you getting a result you did not expect?

Comment: Is this homework? I would say, if version 1 works and you understand how it works, stick with that version.

Comment: I'M expecting to print in all uppercase if the number of uppercase letters is more than the lower case letters, else all lower case, my first method worked but in my 2nd method its only showing in lowercase even if the number of uppercase letter is more than lowercase letters.

Comment: @JonTout It's not homework, I'm trying to learn new and shorter way to write code in less word. or u can say in different methods

Comment: While there are ways to make the code shorter, your first version is the most straight-forward and efficient one. It makes a single pass over the word. I would simply change the loop to be over the letters themselves: `for c in str1`. There is rarely a real need to loop over indexes in Python... Regarding your second version, `u` and `l` are not defined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @HiFile the best file manager is the most succinct, but this will address why your second method doesn't work.

Your second method almost works. You are just not assigning the output of `count_up_and_low(word)` to anything. You can use tuple unpacking to fix this (edited line shown with comment):

```
def count_up_and_low(word):
    u = [x for x in word if x.isupper()]
    l = [x for x in word if x.islower()]
    return len(u),len(l) 

word="HEY THERE WHATS up"
u, l = count_up_and_low(word) # only edited this line
if u>l:
  print(word.upper())
else:
  print(word.lower())
```

Comment: No problem. In future, try to also post any error messages you are receiving. Good luck with the learning :)

Comment: would keep in mind before asking next time

Answer (score 1):

How about counting like this?

```
upper_count = sum(c.isupper() for c in word)
lower_count = sum(c.islower() for c in word)
if upper_count > lower_count:
  print(word.upper())
else:
  print(word.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

## You should do this

```
str1 = "HEY tHeRE Whats UP"
lower_count = len([i for i in str1.replace(' ','') if i.islower()]) 
print(lower_count, '\t', len(str1.replace(' ','')) - lower_count)
```

Answer (score -1):

Same as your first way, I use `c>='A' and c<='Z'` to determine the no. of upper and lower cases

```
str1 = "HEY tHeRE Whats UP"

no_of_ucase, no_of_lcase = 0,0

for c in str1:
    if c>='A' and c<='Z':
        no_of_ucase += 1
    if c>='a' and c<='z':
        no_of_lcase += 1

print("Input string is: ", str1)
print("Total number of uppercase letters: ", no_of_ucase)
print("Total number of lowercase letters: ", no_of_lcase)
```

Result:

```
Input string is:  HEY tHeRE Whats UP
Total number of uppercase letters:  9
Total number of lowercase letters:  6
```

I hope this help

Comment: This won't work for accentuated vowels or special characters like "ç" or "ñ". `"á".islower()` should return True but in your case it's ignored and not counted

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. And it completely ignores the fact that there are other characters than just A-Z. You just ignore all non-english alphabets.